# draggable out the parent element

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

hello

i tried the draggable function of jquery ui:
$("div.kind_div").draggable({ cursor: 'crosshair', containment: 'document', appendTo: 'body' });

i can drag the kind_div but it remains into the outer div

I want drag it in all body of my page

how can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

<strike>have you tried setting containment to window ?</strike>

You need to change the overflow to none or <strike>hidden</strike> for it to work ..
also the 'outer' div must not be relative positioned ..

Comment: overflow keep your element inside the parent.